# Combining yaml metadata (header-includes) with Pandoc

Tags: yaml, latex, markdown, pandoc

If I have these files:

text.md:

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pgf-pie}
---

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie{50/, 50/}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

settings.yaml:

```
variables:
    header-includes:
    - \pagecolor{black}
```

and I compile them with pandoc with the command:

```
pandoc text.md -d settings -o text.pdf
```

...the `header-includes` value in the defaults file `settings.yaml` will overwrite the metadata block in `text.md`, thus failing to compile.

Is there a way to get pandoc to combine the two `header-includes` lists instead?

Answer (score 2):

Combining these `header-includes` lists is not possible.

There are two reasons to this: One, the values from the defaults file always take precedence. In addition, if a name is used both as as a variable and in the metadata, then the variable will be used.

For additional info and discussions of this topic, see these pandoc GitHub issues:

- [Command-line options --css and --include-in-header override corresponding metadata fields instead of accumulating](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3139)
- [Allow defaults to be folded into YAML metadata](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5870)

---

A possible workaround would be to use a "new style" [custom writer](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/doc/custom-writers.md#new-style), as these provide write access to both metadata and variables:

```lua
function Writer (doc, opts)
  local includes_tmpl = pandoc.template.compile('$header-includes$')
  local vars = {['header-includes'] = opts.variables['header-includes'] or ''}

  -- Write header-includes, once with variables, once without (thus
  -- allowing metadata values to be used instead)
  opts.variables['header-includes'] =
    pandoc.write(doc, 'latex', {template=includes_tmpl, variables=vars}) ..
    '\n' ..
    pandoc.write(doc, 'latex', {template=includes_tmpl})

  return pandoc.write(doc, 'latex', opts)
end
```

Note, however, that this currently requires the development version, so you'd need to use a [nightly build](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/actions?query=workflow%3ANightly). You'll also need to explicitly specify the template and PDF engine, e.g., `--template=default.latex --pdf-engine=xelatex`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  From the GitHub issues you provided, it seems that this is still unresolved.  Do you know of any other ways by which `header-includes` metadata can be combined, or if there are any workarounds?  Would I need to use Lua filters for this?

Comment: @ban_javascript I've added the outline for a possible workaround to the answer. Another possibility is to use a Lua filter to read the variables from a file and to merge them with the metadata. Neither is very pleasant, tbh.